# Accents (acute, tilde etc..) not working anymore after windows update in native apps

Tags: windows, keyboard

This week my Windows 10 was updated. I noticed that keyboard accents are not working anymore in native apps. (´ ~ ` á ã à).

It Works good with UWP apps like Edge or Cortana. but it doesen't Works anymore on native apps like chrome or even notepad.

Is there is a know issue for this updated?

I already removed and added the keboard layout and language input.

Comment: I've often seen the keyboard setting switch by itself for no apparent reason; going down to the input language setting and checking it usually reveals that, so I just set it back to what it should be. This has been an unacknowleged Windows bug since Windows 7.